# PHP + CURL http response headers

Tags: php, curl

I am currently attempting to configure a CURL & PHP function found online that when called checks if the HTTP response headers is in the 200-300 range to determine if the web page is up. This is successful once ran against an individual website with the code below (not the function itself but the if statements etc) The function returns true or false depending on the range of the HTTP Response header:

```
$page = "www.google.com";
$page = gzdecode($page); 
if (Visit($page))
{
   echo $page;
   echo " Is OK <br>";       
}
else
{
     echo $page;
     echo "  Is DOWN <br>";       
}
```

However when running against an array of URL's stored within the script through the use of a for each loop it reports every webpage within the list as down despite that the code is the same bar the added for loop of course.

Does anyone know what the issue may be surrounding this?

Edit - adding Visit function
My bad sorry, not fully thinking. 
The visit function is the following:

```
function Visit($url){
   $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";$ch=curl_init();
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
   $page=curl_exec($ch);
   //echo curl_error($ch);
   $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
   curl_close($ch);
   if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<310) return true;
   else return false;
}
```

The `foreach` loop as mentioned looks like this:

```
foreach($Urls as $URL)
{
$page = $URL;
$page = gzdecode($page);
if (Visit($page))
```

The `if` loop for the visit part is the same as before.

Comment: So we should just GUESS what this `visit()` function is doing? How do you expect us to help debug code which you haven't shown at all?

Comment: I can't see any loop here.

Comment: My bad sorry, not fully thinking.

Answer (score 0):

```
$page = $URL;
$page = gzdecode($page);
```

Why are you trying to uncompress the non-compressed URL? Assuming you really meant to uncompress the *content returned from the URL*, why would the remote server server compress it when you you've told it that the client does not support compression? Why are you fetching the entire page to see the headers?

The code you've shown us here *has never worked*

Comment: The uncompression was for when testing against other URL's. Forgot to remove it during the example. However it does return a 302 response when running this code with the uncompressing.

The code works as expected when ran against 1 URL on its own as seen above.  The issue is in relation when attempting to run an array of URL's at it then it outputs that all are down, despite whjen ran individually they all report as up.

Comment: You won't see a 302 response when you've specified CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER